# Are git messages standard?

Tags: git, logging, message, git-clone

I should programmatically capture the git client messages to understand which type of error occurred (auth failure, auth required, etc.).

For example :

```
remote: Invalid username or password.  
If you log in via a third party service you must ensure you have an account password
set in your account profile. 
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://username:password@bitbucket.org'
```

Is this a standard message (that doesn't depend by the git client version) so I can parse it in order to understand that a authentication failure happened ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git messages DO change from version to version. And they can change based upon the local settings of the repository and the response the remote origin is designed to output in the case of errors. Some Git servers always respond with the same message regardless of the error - be it that authentication failed or that you don't have permissions to access the repository. GitHub's responses are different from BitBucket's for example.

What is the requirement of capturing these messages? What is your end goal? Are you attempting to log the output and bring it to the attention of an administrator?

Comment: Hi Adam, I'm writing a repository git managment web application, that allows users to interact with git sending clones / push / pull  by a js git client wrapper. When the user sends a git clone command with wrong credentials I should capture this information in order to notify it. I cannot send the complete git error response because it shows the wrong password on gui (info disclosure), so I'd like to have an error code but this is not feasible, because I cannot get this info from git client, so I was trying to get and clean git messages but if they changes I cannot use this approach.

Comment: Well, you're right, I just try with gitlab and receive a different error message for the same wrong auth request... so I should know every possible format of message for a specific type of error, this cannot be a good approach... I have to send a generic git error message to user, or I have to send the git client message with wrong credentials disclosure ... (maybe I could also use this second approach because it's an app for local use, but I don't know if it could be a bad design choice)

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a terrible design choice. Especially sending the credentials back - that's a big security risk.

Comment: Can't you just intercept the message you receive back, and strip out the wrong password before it reaches the GUI? You will know what was sent, because your application is the one sending it.

Comment: Actually, more to the point, why are you reinventing the wheel? GitLab CE is free. (Community Edition) and it's fully-featured, close to GitHub. (Plenty of bugs, not perfect). Why is that not a solution for you?

Comment: Well, of course, you're right :) but I've to do this cause I've to  integrate it in a more complex Node project. it's just a very simple js module to do clone, push and pull :)  . Anyway, you give me the best idea,  I didn't think at this ... I intercept the message, check if there's password / user string equals to password received by client, and simply remove it from the message !!! Thanks very much !!!